# Updating integer column from jsonb member fails with: column is of type integer but expression is of type jsonb

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-json

In a PostgreSQL 9.5 table I have an `integer` column `social`.

When I try to update it in a stored procedure given the following JSON data (an array with 2 objects, each having a "social" key) in the `in_users` variable of type `jsonb`:

> ```
> '[{"sid":"12345284239407942","auth":"ddddc1808197a1161bc22dc307accccc",**"social":3**,"given":"Alexander1","family":"Farber","photo":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/1015428423940942\/picture?type=large","place":"Bochum,
> Germany","female":0,"stamp":1450102770},
>   {"sid":"54321284239407942","auth":"ddddc1808197a1161bc22dc307abbbbb",**"social":4**,"given":"Alxander2","family":"Farber","photo":null,"place":"Bochum,
> Germany","female":0,"stamp":1450102800}]'::jsonb
> ```

Then the following code is failing:

```
    FOR t IN SELECT * FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_users)
    LOOP
            UPDATE words_social SET
                    social = t->'social',
            WHERE sid = t->>'sid';
    END LOOP;
```

with the error message:

```
ERROR:  column "social" is of type integer but expression is of type jsonb
LINE 3:                         social = t->'social',
                                         ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I have tried changing that line to:

```
social = t->'social'::int,
```

but then I get the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "social"
LINE 3:                         social = t->'social'::int,
                                            ^
```

Why doesn't PostgreSQL recognize that the data is `integer`?

From the [JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE) I was having the impression that JSON number would be auto-converted to PostgreSQL numeric type.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit that effectively added a new question. Please post a new question instead if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single set-based SQL command is far more efficient than looping:

```
UPDATE words_social w
SET    social = (iu->>'social')::int
FROM   JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_users) iu  -- in_user = function variable
WHERE  w.sid = iu->>'sid';                -- type of sid?
```

To answer your original question:

> Why doesn't PostgreSQL recognize that the data is integer?

Because you were trying to convert the `jsonb` value to `integer`. In your solution you already found that you need the `->>` operator instead of `->` to extract `text`, which can be cast to `integer`.

Your second attempt added a second error:

<strike>`t->'social'::int`</strike>

In addition to the above: [operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). The cast operator `::` binds stronger than the json operator `->`. Like you found yourself already, you really want:

```
(t->>'social')::int
```

Very similar case on dba.SE:

- [Querying JSONB in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128418/3684)

Comment: Erwin, thank you for your guidance, but I am not sure how to apply your suggestion to my case - where I loop through jsonb array and do `UPDATE` - `IF NOT FOUND THEN` - `INSERT`. Please see my [words_merge_users() function](https://gist.github.com/afarber/c40b9fc5447335db7d24) for more context.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: There is probably a very elegant solution with the new `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE` In Postgres 9.5. But please post your new question as new question.

Comment: Erwin, I've posted [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393252/syntax-error-in-upsert-test-code) but it seems not to work with `ON CONFLICT` for some JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up using:

```
FOR t IN SELECT * FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_users)
LOOP
        UPDATE words_social SET
                social = (t->>'social')::int
        WHERE sid = t->>'sid';

        IF NOT FOUND THEN
                INSERT INTO words_social (social)
                VALUES ((t->>'social')::int);
        END IF;
END LOOP;
```