# Syntax error in UPSERT test code

Tags: postgresql, insert, upsert, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-json

I am trying to test the new PostgreSQL [upsert syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) with the following test code, but get the syntax error:

```
test=> CREATE TABLE test1 (
test(>         key1 integer PRIMARY KEY check (key1 > 0),
test(>         key2 integer check (key2 > 0)
test(> );
CREATE TABLE

test=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert(IN in_json_array jsonb)
test->         RETURNS void AS
test-> $func$
test$>         UPDATE test1 t SET     
test$>         t.key1 = (obj->>'key1')::int,
test$>         t.key2 = (obj->>'key2')::int
test$>         FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_json_array) obj
test$>         WHERE  t.key1 = obj->'key1'
test$>         ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET
test$>         key1 = excluded.key1,
test$>         key2 = excluded.key2;
test$> 
test$> $func$ LANGUAGE sql;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 9:         ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET
                ^
```

Why does the above code fail please?

Also, the `test1` table has several constraints (non-negative values and the unique primary key). How to address the uniqueness constraint only?

**UPDATE 2:** I have switched from `UPDATE` to `INSERT` (sorry for the silly mistake!), but am still struggling with the syntax:

```
test=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert(IN in_json_array jsonb)
test->         RETURNS void AS
test-> $func$
test$>         INSERT into test1 AS t (t.key1, t.key2)
test$>         VALUES ((obj->>'key1')::int, (obj->>'key2')::int)
test$>         FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_json_array) obj
test$>         WHERE t.key1 = obj->'key1'
test$>         ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET
test$>         t.key1 = excluded.key1,
test$>         t.key2 = excluded.key2;
test$> $func$ LANGUAGE sql;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 6:         FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_json_array) obj
                ^
```

I have also tried to change the JSON-line to:

```
SELECT obj FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_json_array)
```

but that fails too...

Here is my test code for your convenience:

```
select upsert('[{"key1":1,"key2":2},{"key1":3,"key2":4}]'::jsonb);
select upsert('[{"key1":1,"key2":2},{"key1":1,"key2":4}]'::jsonb);
```

Comment: `language plpgsql` requires a `begin ... end` block. You probably want `language sql`

Comment: Thanks, but this hasn't helped (neither `BEGIN / END` nor `LANGUAGE SQL`)

Comment: `PostgreSQL 9.5.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16), 64-bit` coming from `postgresql95-server-9.5.1-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64` package for CentOS 6.7 Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `from` clause you can't use `values`. It's either `insert into .. values (..)` **or** `insert into .. select ... from ...` but not both.

You also can't reference the target table from the insert in the `select` clause that feeds the insert. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with that.

You also need to qualify which "conflict" should be trapped by specifying the PK columns or the *name* of the constraint that should be handled. In your case it should be the pk column:

All that put together, the function should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert(IN in_json_array jsonb)
        RETURNS void AS
$func$
    INSERT into test1 (key1, key2)
    select distinct on ((obj->>'key1')::int)
             (obj->>'key1')::int, 
             (obj->>'key2')::int
    FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(in_json_array) obj
    ON CONFLICT (key1) DO 
      UPDATE SET key1 = excluded.key1,
                 key2 = excluded.key2;
$func$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

The `distinct on ()` will make sure that only one value for key1 will be returned by the select to avoid the "*ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time*" error. Note that without an `order by` in the select it is basically "random" which key is being chosen. If you want to pick a specific one, you need to add an `order by` to the `select`

Comment: When calling `select upsert('[{"key1":1,"key2":2},{"key1":1,"key2":4}]'::jsonb);` (i.e. same PK in JSON array) there is unfortunately an `ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time`

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: well you are passing the same key twice. Apparently the `on conflict` clause cannot handle that. You would need to adjust the `select` statement to only retrieve unique keys from the json array

Comment: Ok thanks, I will stick with `LOOP` with `UPDATE - NOT FOUND - INSERT`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35231171/165071

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: which of the two keys should be used? You could use a `distinct on ()` to make sure you only get each `key1` once.

Comment: Thank you. Another question: is it possible to write `ON CONFLICT (key1, key2)` if I have a "json-feeded" table (I actually do in my real application) with `PRIMARY KEY(key1, key2)`?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: if the PK is actually `(key1, key2)`  then you **have** to use `ON CONFLICT (key1, key2)`

Answer (score 6):

As this is the top Google result for error:

```
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
```

I will add that It may be caused by a **duplicate conflict VALUES**, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO distributors (did, dname)
VALUES 
    (5, 'Gizmo Transglobal'), 
    (5, 'Associated Computing, Inc')
ON CONFLICT (did) DO UPDATE SET dname = EXCLUDED.dname;
```

In this case we try to insert two values with `dim` set to `5`. As `dim` is the index it cannot have conflict in query itself.

I encountered this error when implementing microservice and processing requests, some of them having duplicate records.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. THANK YOU!